# Adding equal space time intervals to an xts/data.table object in R

Tags: r, data.table, xts

Sorry if this is a fairly easy question but I am quite new to R and `xts` and `data.table` and I wasn't able to find anything online which could help me. I have data which looks similar to the following:

```
    Time                 |   Volume   |   ....
-----------------------------------------------
2005-03-02 11:23:40.111  |    123     |   ....
2005-03-02 11:23:42.675  |    503     |   ....
2005-03-02 11:23:42.749  |    -2      |   ....
2005-03-02 11:23:42.912  |    200     |   ....
2005-03-02 11:23:43.002  |    -76     |   ....
2005-03-02 11:23:43.819  |    -134    |   ....
2005-03-02 11:23:45.353  |    506     |   ....
```

I would like to create equal spaced time intervals at every second such that the above table turns into the new table below:

```
    Time                 |   Volume   |   ....
-----------------------------------------------
2005-03-02 11:23:40      |    123     |   ....
2005-03-02 11:23:41      |    NA      |   ....
2005-03-02 11:23:42      |    701     |   ....
2005-03-02 11:23:43      |    -210    |   ....
2005-03-02 11:23:44      |    NA      |   ....
2005-03-02 11:23:45      |    506     |   ....
```

More specifically, I would like for the equally spaced seconds interval to start from 09:00 and finish at 17:00 each day.

Is there a good way of doing this? Thanks in advance

EDIT: Here is the `dput` output:

```
structure(list(HFTtimevec = structure(c(1122855297, 1122855297, 
1122855309, 1122855310.87, 1122855381.82), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Price = c(3.48, 3.48, 3.48, 21.32, 3.48), Volume = c(2947, 
1398, 920, 4000, 19735)), .Names = c("HFTtimevec", "Price", "Volume"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002710788>)
```

Comment: Please post the output of `dput(DT[1:5, list(Time, Volume)])` (replace `DT` with your data.table).  We need a reproducible example to help.

Comment: @NathanWerth sure, here's the dput output, I included the price column as well just to give a bit more of an idea of how the data looks. Thanks!

Comment: How many days do you want to create? Just one day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
dat<-data.table(dat)
dat[,Time:=strptime(HFTtimevec, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")]
dat1<-dat[,list(Volume=sum(Volume)),by=list(Time)]
```

Here you are creating all the data points in Time variable:

```
dt<-data.table(Time=seq(
  ISOdatetime(year=2005, mont=03, day=02, hour=09, min=0, sec=0),
  ISOdatetime(year=2005, mont=03, day=02, hour=17, min=0, sec=0),by="sec"))

newdT<-merge(dt, dat1, by="Time", all.x=T)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I do have something similar to that by using the line `aggregate(`True Volume` ~ format(as.POSIXct(HFTtimevec), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), data= HFTsubset1, sum)`, however I would like to add additional rows to my data.table object which have equal-spaced seconds intervals (similar to what I gave in the example above)